# How to read a file one step back of project folder in Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to read a file from a path one step back of the project folder when deployed on tomcat server.
For eg:

Project folder :

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/Test/index.jsp
```

Now i want to read a file which is in webapps folder

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/test.xml
```

using

```
File inputFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("test.xml"));
```

How can i implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `File inputFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("../test.xml"));`

Comment: No its comming like :

java.io.FileNotFoundException: apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/Test\..\test.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: How about `File inputFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("") + "../test.xml");` then?

Comment: No, Now the error is
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: apache-tomcat-7.0.63\webapps\Test..\test.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: Err, maybe [`File inputFile = new File(new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("")).getParent() + "/test.xml");`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_getparent.htm)?

Comment: Yes, its working
Thanks

Comment: Please update your question, it's not just about "reading file one step back" but more like "reading file from parent directory of context base path".

Answer (score 2):

You have to obtain parent directory path from the base context directory:

```
File contextBasePath = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(""));
```

And then concatenate it with desired file name:

```
String fileName = "test.xml";
File inputFile = new File(contextBasePath.getParent() + '/' + fileName);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
```

Gives the file system path of the cotext root, but different containers may return ending slash or not (even different versions of same vendor). so the fail-safe access to your file can be achieved with these lines (asuming it does exist)

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/").replaceAll("[/\\\\]$", "")+ "/../test.xml";
```

You can check if java can load the file with

```
new File(path).exists()
```

Comment: Many libraries are very strict when it comes to leading slashes. Are you sure it's supposed to be "/../test.xml" and not "../test.xml"?

Comment: yes, I tested it before submitting (glassfish 4).
Most of the time path-values are not supposed to include ending slashes.

Comment: The question is if should include the _leading_ slash -- `/../test.xml`, on Unix, means `/text.xml`, aka the file text.xml at root.

Comment: Is in root regarding to context, not the filesystem root.